# FFMPEG stops converting

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I've got Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which runs Wowza Media Server, so I use FFmpeg as a transcoder for live streaming and JWplayer on my website. But ffmpeg always stops converting, and I have to input the command again and again. So here is the command:

```
nohup ffmpeg -i rtsp://log:pass@<cameraip>:554/live1.sdp -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f flv -b 5000k -s 480x270 -y rtmp://<serverip>:1935/live/camera.stream &
```

And that's what i get

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.10-4:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:56:59 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[rtsp @ 0x25317a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 150.00 (150/1) -> 1000.00 (1000/1)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://log:pass@<cameraip>:554/live1.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP/RTP stream 1 from DCS-2132L
    comment         : live1.sdp with v2.0
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 75 fps, 1k tbr, 90k tbn, 150 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj420p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x2539f80] w:640 h:360 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[scale @ 0x253a940] w:640 h:360 fmt:yuvj420p -> w:480 h:270 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0x2531120] channel_layout not specified
[ac3 @ 0x2531120] No channel layout specified. The encoder will guess the layout, but it might be incorrect.
[ac3 @ 0x2531120] invalid bit rate
Output #0, avi, to 'rtmp://<serverip>:1935/live/camera.stream':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 480x270 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1024 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 22050 Hz, mono, flt, 1024 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion tries to use the `ac3` encoder for audio and fails when setting the bitrate. I'm pretty sure that AC3 audio is not what you want for streaming video, and you could also use an [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) encoder like `libx264` instead of plain [MPEG-4 Part II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2) video (`mpeg-4`).

With H.264 video you don't even need ~5 MBit/s bitrate—you could achieve the same visual quality with lower bitrates. Depending on the input you could try ~2 MBit/s or even less. 480×270 is a rather low resolution and I'd guess that even 500 kBit/s would look acceptable.

Moreover, you're using an outdated and buggy program called `ffmpeg` [which isn't really from FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv) but a fork of the project. Please [download a recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) to continue developing with. You can also compile it yourself; it doesn't take that long.

Also, `-y` is a global option and needs to come before the input option.

Your command might look as follows:

```
ffmpeg -y -i <input> \
-f flv \
-c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k \
-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
-s 480x270 rtmp://<serverip>:1935/live/camera.stream
```

Comment: so, thank you for your reply. I've just downloaded FFMPEG from here http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/ so how can i install it?

Comment: You can run it from wherever you downloaded it, e.g. call `~/downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg` instead of `ffmpeg`. Or you copy the `ffmpeg` file to some directory on your machine which you have in your `PATH`. For example: `cp ~/downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg_static` and then use `ffmpeg_static` instead of `ffmpeg`. Or you copy it to `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` and change your `~/.bash_profile` and add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` at the end.

Comment: here it is, the sound has just disappeard after 10 minutes of work 

log is here-> http://navidu.in/nohup.txt

Please, check it

Comment: Possibly related to the non-monotonous DTS. Unfortunately I don't know that much about how ffmpeg parses streams. I'm not exactly sure if that'd help, but you could try to add `-fflags igndts` or `-fflags sortdts`.

Comment: thank you, I will try. 

here is the mistake that is perhaps connected with sound. its from the above log 

[aac @ 0xaaa65e0] Queue input is backward in time

Comment: error* instead of mistake) 
here it is, the error:
[aac @ 0xaaa65e0] Queue input is backward in time

Comment: So, perhaps that will help:

So my rtmp stream is played by JWplayer, but there is no sound. My ip-camera sound format is G.711 and all I need is sound in JW player) perhaps there are some other ways to solve this problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: perhaps you can give some advice

Comment: I don't have a concrete idea now but I see you've [posted another question](http://superuser.com/questions/719265/ffmpeg-sound-troubles) already.

Comment: Yes, the problem is still the same (